# How to create you own pass in LLVm?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am new to LLVM and I am trying to build my own pass. After reading through the documentation on Writing an LLVM Pass. I tried to create my own pass by adding a directory in the Transforms directory. However, when I try to make my source, it gives an error "make: *** No rule to make target".

Do I have to rebuild LLVM if I want to make a new pass? If so, it would be very time consuming as I am running this on a Debian VM and it takes approximately half an hour to build it.

Let me know if there is a way around this. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
Yes, I have the makefile. I am following the steps mentioned in the documentation.

```
# Makefile for hello pass

# Path to top level of LLVM hierarchy
LEVEL = ../../..

# Name of the library to build
LIBRARYNAME = Trial

# Make the shared library become a loadable module so the tools can
# dlopen/dlsym on the resulting library.
LOADABLE_MODULE = 1

# Include the makefile implementation stuff
include $(LEVEL)/Makefile.common
```

I am trying to make a simple function pass named Trial.

Comment: do you have Makefile?

Comment: You're better off asking this question in the LLVM irc channel or their mailing list.

Answer (score 6):

If you have an working installation of `llvm` in your `$PATH` then instead of putting the files in the Transforms directory as the documentation mentions, you can do the following

```
<create basic_block_pass.cpp with pass name myPass in any location>

$ clang++ -c basic_block_pass.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags`
$ clang++ -shared -o pass.so basic_block_pass.o `llvm-config --ldflags`
$ opt -load ./pass.so -myPass < hello.bc > /dev/null
```

If you create a `Makefile` to do the above steps you have a nice build system in place.

Comment: is this mentionned anywhere in the official docs?